# VS Code extension Api to get the Range of the whole text of a document?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I haven't found a good way to do it. My current approach is to select all first:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.selectAll").then(() =>{
    textEditor.edit(editBuilder => editBuilder.replace(textEditor.selection, code));
    vscode.commands.executeCommand("cursorMove", {"to": "viewPortTop"});
});
```

which is not ideal because it flashes when doing selection then replacement.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This may not be robust, but I've been using this:

```
var firstLine = textEditor.document.lineAt(0);
var lastLine = textEditor.document.lineAt(textEditor.document.lineCount - 1);
var textRange = new vscode.Range(firstLine.range.start, lastLine.range.end);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is better than selecting all then get range from selection.

Answer (score 21):

I'm hoping this example might help:

```js
var editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
if (!editor) {
    return; // No open text editor
}

var selection = editor.selection;
var text = editor.document.getText(selection);
```

**Source**: [**vscode extension samples** > **document editing sample**](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/document-editing-sample/src/extension.ts#L8-L20)

Comment: This does not produce a range

Answer (score 13):

You could create a `Range`, which is just one character longer than the document text and use `validateRange` to trim it to the correct `Range`. The method finds the last line of text and uses the last character as the end `Position` of the `Range`.

```
let invalidRange = new Range(0, 0, textDocument.lineCount /*intentionally missing the '-1' */, 0);
let fullRange = textDocument.validateRange(invalidRange);
editor.edit(edit => edit.replace(fullRange, newText));
```

Answer (score 7):

A shorter example:

```
const fullText = document.getText()

const fullRange = new vscode.Range(
    document.positionAt(0),
    document.positionAt(fullText.length - 1)
)
```

Comment: There's something wrong with this piece of code. I don't know exactly where is the problem. However, I used this snippet in my vscode extension and it triggered a bug at the end of the selection. I switched to use Jan Dolejsi's solution and it works well.

Comment: If your goal is to get the entire doc text then the first line in this answer is all you need. Not very efficient to get all text just to get a range though. (Side note: when using getWordRangeAtPosition to get a range for getText, if the range returned is undefined you will end up with all text which isn't efficient in a hover)